# excluding certain recipient addresses from an array iteration

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How can I iterate through an storage array in a function which signature defines an input-array parameter declaring excluded recipient addresses that should not be targeted in the iteration of a for loop?

Comment: Could you share more technical details. What is your expected input, what is your expected output, what does the skeleton of your function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two arrays, one with the recipients list `recipients` and one with the exceptions `exceptions`, you could do this:

```
function send_with_exceptions(address[] recipients, address[] exceptions) public {
        for(uint i=0;i<recipients.length;i++){
            bool flag;
            for(uint k=0;k<exceptions.length;k++){
                if(recipients[i]==exceptions[k]){
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if(!flag){
                // do your transactions here
            }
        }
    }
```

This can be simplified if you have your exceptions in a mapping:

```
 mapping (address=>bool) public exceptions;
 function send_with_exceptions2(address[] recipients) public {
        for(uint i=0;i<recipients.length;i++){
            if(!exceptions[recipients[i]]){
                // do your transactions here
            }
        }
    }
```

The value for an address in the mapping exceptions will be true if the address should be avoided and zero otherwise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if recipients grows to thousands, how should I avoid that the Tx exceeds the block limit ?

Comment: I think this is something you should have added to your question. You may fix a number of recipients and call the function several times, as needed. There is not a magical solution for this.